# C# code for sending email in mvc4 doubts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, smtp

am am doing a website in mvc4 using c#. currently i test this in localhost. I want to send passwords to registering persons email. i use the following code.

//model

```
 public void SendPasswordToMail(string newpwd,string email)
    {
        string mailcontent ="Your password is "+ newpwd;
        string toemail = email.Trim();
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("paru.mr@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add(toemail);
            mail.Subject = "Your New Password";
            mail.Body = mailcontent;
            //Attachment attachment = new Attachment(filename);
            //mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            SmtpServer.Port = 25;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("me", "password");  //is that NetworkCredential
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

//controller

```
  string newpwd;
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendPassword(int Id,string email)
    {
        bool IsMember=CheckMember(Id);
        if (IsMember == true)
        {
             newpwd = new Member().RandomPaswordGen();
        }
       .......//here i want to call that model
        return View();
    }
```

Is the model is right or not. and what should be the return type of this model(now it is void and i dont know how this call in controller). and how to get default NetworkCredential. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Network Credential is the user name and password of the email sender (as in case of company a defualt mail address like noreply@abccompany.com). 
Hence use you gmail user name and password in that case.
And you could use following code to send email.

```
var client = new SmtpClient()
                         {
                             Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                             Port = 587,
                             EnableSsl = true,

                         };
        var from = new MailAddress(Email);
        var to = new MailAddress(Email);
        var message = new MailMessage(from, to) { Body = Message, IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHtml };

        message.Body += Environment.NewLine + Footer;
        message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Subject = Subject;
        message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        var nc = new NetworkCredential("me@gmail.com", "password");
        client.Credentials = nc;

        //send email
        client.Send(message);
```